# Как отправить массив через ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

при отправке массива

```
var obj = {
                     'generalFields':{
                         'title':$('input#title').val(),
                         'keywords':$('input#keywords').val(),
                         'mainCategory':$('select#mainCategory').val(),
                         'subCategory':subCategory,
                         'typeCategory':$('select#selecttypeCategory').val(),
                         'description': $('input#description').val(),
                         'comments':$('input[name="comments"]:checked').val(),
                         'fulltext': $('div[role="textbox"]').text(),
                         'imgs':name_file
                     },
                     'optionFields':fieldsAdvert
                 }
```

через ajax

```
$.ajax({                             
            url: '/addNewAdvert',
            type:'post',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        });
```

выходит ошибка Uncaught TypeError: cyclic object value

в лог получаю

```
   generalFields: Object { title: "", mainCategory: "22", typeCategory: "22", … }
   optionFields: Array(31) [ input, input, select#rooms_apartament.advertFields, … ]
```

Comment: Для начала уберите массив. Потом постепенно добавляйте

Comment: убрать массив это еще понять можно, а что значит постепенно добавлять?

Comment: Добавьте сначала 10 элементов. Потом ещё пока не получите ошибку

Comment: Ого, да вы похоже отправляете целые html элементы! Что у вас находится в переменной `fieldsAdvert`?

Comment: черным по белому же написано - циклические ссылки.

Comment: условно у вас сткрутура `let a = { }; a.obj = a` и вы пытаетесь это сериализовать. По факту будет бесконечная рекурсия при сериализация, либо придется игнорировать циклы.  Поскольку последнее нарушает структуру данных вот вам исключение.